# Is there a way to group rows in ag-grid without the enterprise version?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid in my application and want to have a row have child rows that expand when clicked (similar to master/detail, row grouping, or tree data). However, all of these are enterprise features. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality without an enterprise license?

- Row Grouping: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/,
- Master/Detail: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/,
- Tree Data: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

But depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you might be able to fake grouping visually using full width rows:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/#detailed-full-width-example

Comment: Thanks full width rows with another ag-grid rendered inside does the trick!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks clicking up vote and/or accepting the answer as the correct one.

Comment: No problem, turns out it ended up being easier for our purposes to not use a full width cell and instead render another grid inside a regular cell and use CSS to tweak to our liking.

Comment: @dk4477 Hi, I'm facing the exact issue, do you mind to post an example of your solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn, unfortunately, I don't have access to the codebase anymore. Essentially we rendered a new ag-grid into the cell if a button was pressed. We would then change the height of that cell to fit the new grid. It's been a while since I've looked at ag-grid but I'll try and put together an example.

Comment: An example would really help if somebody has done it successfully.